# UWP get live webcam video stream

Tags: c#, webcam, windows-10-iot-core, uwp-xaml, azure-cognitive-services

I was looking into the [`MediaCapture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241124) class, however it doesn't seem to expose what I'm looking for. I want the live `Stream` from the web cam - not to record it or preview it. I'm working on the **Microsoft Cognitive Services Emotion API** and I want to follow [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/blob/master/Emotion/Windows/Sample-WPF/EmotionDetectionUsingVideoPage.xaml.cs#L68), but instead of getting a local video stream from the file system - I want to get a `Stream` from a web cam.

Comment: MediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(
  MediaEncodingProfile encodingProfile, 
  IRandomAccessStream stream
) ?

Comment: @pijemcolu, that records the stream but does **not** expose it. I specifically mention that this is *not* going to work for me in my question.

Comment: Have a look at this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-mediacapture#capture-a-photo). I think this is what you are looking for. Access the memory stream from the camera and capture a frame/photo to send to the Microsoft Cognitive Services Emotion API.

Comment: @Shivam, actually what I'm looking for is the video stream. I do not want to take a photo and send that, I want the stream from the web cam.

Comment: David, I have the same problem (unable to expose the video stream in a UWP app) - did you solve this problem?

Comment: Nope... can't figure it out

Answer (score -2):

The Microsoft Cognitive Services Video APIs, including Emotion, are REST APIs, not streaming APIs, so your scenario is not supported.

What you can do instead is periodically capture a frame and make RESTful calls to one of the image APIs.

Comment: This answer not only avoids answering the question but it is also completely wrong. The [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/blob/master/Emotion/Windows/Sample-WPF/EmotionDetectionUsingVideoPage.xaml.cs#L68) that I shared has an example of passing a stream into the API. I am already doing the temporary capture and post approach, but wanted to follow their example of the streaming video. Please read up on the MIME type "application/octet-stream".

Comment: The fact that something is a REST API doesn't mean you can't pass a stream. As far as I know, there is no distinction like "REST" versus "streaming" API's. This answer is indeed completely wrong, even on the fundamental level.